# ModuleNotFoundError using "classic" import on module imported from importlib

Tags: python, import, module, python-importlib

#### TL,DR

I've :

```
mod = import_module('path.module')
```

After that, what i want/need to do :

```
from mod.script import func
```

But that give me :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod.script'
```

**Warning** : call it using "mod.script.func()" or something like that doesn't respond to my need (project constraint), i search how to have a syntax like "from [module_imported_from_importlib] import XXX"

### Introduction :

I need to split an existing code in different folder with multiple version. The goal is to have different part in the app, with each part using a specified version of an other part.

Example tree :

```
ref.py 
block1 
__init__.py
- v1
| __init__.py
|- __init__.py
|- script1.py
 block2
 __init__.py
- v1
| __init__.py
|-- __init__.py
|-- script2.py
- v2
|- __init__.py
|-- __init__.py
|-- script2.py
```

With this, i need to run : 
/block2/v1/script2.py functions in /block1/v1/script1.py

### Goal

what i try to do is to specify where script1 should take the "script2" (in v1 or v2 in block2) using the same syntax but just specifying the block without the version (that will change) :

old script1.py :

```
from script2 import <func>
```

new script1.py

```
from block2.script2 import <func>
```

### Code

I've tryed a lot of thing without success, now i'm here that seems to be close to solution but i can't find it (maybe it's not possible ?) :

in block1/v1/**init**.py :

```
from importlib import import_module, reload

MODULE = import_module('block2.v1') # With 'block2.v1' defined as a variable somewhere else (eg in ref.py)
reload(MODULE)
```

in block1/v1/script1.py :

```
from block1.v1 import MODULE as block2
print(block2)
print(f'block2 : {dir(block2)}')
from block2.script2 import test
```

in block2/v1/**init**.py :

```
from block2.v1 import script2

print(script2)
```

in block2/v1/script2.py :

```
def test():
    print("hello")
```

Result of # python block1/v1/script1.py :

```
<module 'block2.v1.script2' from 'xxx/block2/v1/script2.py'>
<module 'block2.v1.script2' from 'xxx/block2/v1/script2.py'>
<module 'block2.v1' from 'xxx/block1/v1/__init__.py'>
block2 : ['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'script2']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "block1/v1/script1.py", line 17, in <module>
    from block2.script2 import test
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'block2.script2'
```

### Expected result

Shortly, I expect to have this call syntax in script 1 :

```
from block2.script2 import test
test()
```

to be able to run my test function

Thanks a lot for help, I don't know it's really clear !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of test, I finally found something nice.

If you want to use a custom module with a custom name, the best to do is to create a module and giving him the name you want :D

**Tree :**

```
/GLOBALCONFIG
|- /module_manager
  |- block1.py
  |- block2.py
  |- blocX..
- module_version_manager
/block1
|- /v1
   |- script1.py
|- /v2
   |- script1.py
/block2
|- /v1
   |- script2.py
|- /v2
   |- script2.py
```

For that I've made a dir named "GLOBALCONFIG" at the project root that contains a .py manager with this :

```
from importlib import import_module
import sys
import os

block1 = sys.modules['block1'] = import_module('block1.v1')
block2 = sys.modules['block2'] = import_module('block2.v1')
```

Using this, i can keep all my import, specifying the version only on the "manager" file, eg :

block1/v1/script1.py :

```
from GLOBALCONFIG.module_manager.block1 import block2
from block2 import script2
```

if I put script2 in block2/v2 or /v3 or any, i just have to change with the right version to use for block2 in block1.py manager and code will still work

Moreover, if you want :
block1/v1 using block2/v1
block1/v2 using block2/v2

You can create a dict that refer the module / version in your global config :

module_version_manager.py :

```
block1_modules_versions = {
    'block1.v1': {
        'block2':'block2.v1',
    }
    'block1.v2': {
        'block2':'block2.v2',
    }
}

block2_modules_versions = {
    'block2.v2': {
        'block1':'block1.v1',
    }
   'block2.v2': {
        'block1':'block1.v2',
    }
}
```

then, in your block1.py manager :

```
from GLOBALCONFIG.module_version_manager import block1_modules_versions
from importlib import import_module
import sys
import os

block1 = sys.modules['u1'] = import_module('.'.join(str.rsplit(sys.argv[0], "/")[3:5])) # give me the current version of the current block : block1.vX
block2 = sys.modules['block2'] = import_module(block1_modules_versions['.'.join(str.rsplit(sys.argv[0], "/")[3:5])]['block2']) # give me the block2 to use for the right block1.vX
```

in block1/v1/script1.py :

```
import sys
sys.argv[0] = __file__ # [path]/block1/v1/script1 => current path of executed script giving the right folder and import the right modules
from GLOBALCONFIG.module_manager.block1 import block1, block2
```

block1 => block1/v1
block2 => block2/v1

But **here is the magical trick** :
in block1/**v2**/script1.py :

```
import sys
sys.argv[0] = __file__
from GLOBALCONFIG.module_manager.block1 import block1, block2
```

block1 => block1/v2
block2 => block2/v2

Different version but exactly the same code

FYI : The sys.argv[0] = **file** that force the current file path is mandatory for me cause my service start using gunicon wsgi:app that made the default path at [venv]/bin/gunicorn but without this constraint, the GLOBALCONFIG import should nicely work

Regards,